# Instalar App en la pantalla de bloqueo (lock-screen)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estimados, alguien sabe si es configurable la instalación de una apps para la pantalla de bloqueo (lock-screen), la idea es que no tenga que desbloquear el patrón para acceder a ella.

**Pd**: es una aplicación que estoy desarrollando, y la idea es programarla para que aparezca en la **pantalla de bloqueo**, por lo que he podido ver se debe trabajar en el `androidmanifest.xml`.

Comment: Buenas creo que aplicación como tal no puedes pero si lo que puedes hacer es algo que sea como las burbujas de Facebook que al darle se abra un contenido que hayas diseñado

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas es en realidad un Widget para acceso rapido, aqui unos ejemplos

https://www.androidpit.com/best-android-lock-screen-apps

Debes tener en cuenta que por seguridad unicamente se pueden habilitar desde la configuracion de seguridad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debe definir el atributo en tu `appwidget-provider` para determinar si tu widget aparece en la pantalla.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

> El atributo `widgetCategory` declara si tu aplicacion Widget se puede
>   visualizar en la pantalla de inicio (`home_screen`), la pantalla de
>   bloqueo (`keyguard`), o ambos. Sólo las versiones de Android
>   anteriores a 5.0 soportan widgets de pantalla de bloqueo. Para Android
>   5.0 y superiores, unicamente `home_screen` es válido.

El `appwidget-provider` para definir tu aplicacion Widget se debe definir dentro del folder `res/xml/` .

y este es un ejemplo

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"
    android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure" 
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo, me a servido un monton!!!    Saludos.